# Transfer files to Esxi datastore using kickstart file

Tags: vmware, esxi

I was trying to place a file on to the esxi host while booting up the system using kickstart process.

I created a.txt file in the iso image, and build the image. When i booted up the system all the files which were present on the iso were visible on the datastore/localdisk except the text file.

Where should I mention so that the file the can also be moved into the host? is there any other way of achiving this thing.

thanks in advance

Comment: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2004582 has some info about how to run pre/post install scripts from `ks.cfg`, but there's not much more documentation. I think it would require something like an extra partition on your removable media, and to reference a script there to perform some post-install process (e.g. copying files across to a datastore).